Эффекты анимации в elementor
А можно сделать так чтобы в elementor объединить два контейнера и назначить им один эффект анимации(например появление слева) и чтобы эти два элемента двигались синхронно. Эти два элемента находятся один ниже другого и синхронную анимацию сделать не получается. Может вы знаете как это сделать? Напишите мне пожалуйста.

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

@aleksandrbarakin ссылка/замечание не в тему. Тут не просто ВП, а ещё и мышевозка. Всё делается в ней.
